# Binding data from SQLite to DataGrid using C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid

I have a method `Load` in `MyController`:

```
public void Load(ItemsControl control, string commandText)
{
    try
    {
        _db.OpenConnection();

        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, _db.Connection))
        using (SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            control.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //...;
    }
}
```

Then in `XAML` I have:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_1" ... AutoGenerateColumns="True" Loaded="DataGrid_1_Loaded">
```

and finally in `DataGrid_1_Loaded()` I'm calling the method `Load()` like this:

```
MyController.Load(DataGrid_1, "CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS content_for_dg AS SELECT name,surname FROM people");
```

When I run the program, I see a little white space at the top of `Data_Grid_1` but no columns and no data. I opened the database with SQLite Browser and the  view `content_for_dg` exists and contains correct data...

What am I missing ? Why the data are not shown in `DataGrid` ?

Comment: I tested the code, and it worked as expected.  Note that I created the data table manually for testing.  Can you put a breakpoint on the line where you set `control.ItemsSource` and verify that the data table does in fact contain data?

Comment: @RyanS thanks for answering. You are right - `dataTable.DataSet = null` at breakpoint...

Answer (score 1):

If I remove `using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, _db.Connection))` and create `SQLiteDataAdapter` this way `SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(commandText, _db.Connection)`, then it works fine...

```
public void Load(ItemsControl control, string commandText)
{
    try
    {
        _db.OpenConnection();

        using (SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(commandText, _db.Connection))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            control.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //...;
    }
}
```